# Results in an article by Siegel

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, zeta-functions

Studying the Eisenstein cocycle by Sczech, I noticed that to understand its connection with the values at negative integers with zeta functions it is necessary to understand the resuts by Siegel in

Siegel, Carl Ludwig.
*Über die Fourierschen Koeffizienten von Modulformen*. 
Nachr. Akad. Wiss. Göttingen Math.-Phys. Kl. II 1970 1970 15–56.

Sadly, I don't have access to this paper, and the review in mathscinet is in german; even worst, I do not read german (which I'm slowly learning). **Do  you know any reference in english, french or spanish, that shows Siegel's results, hopefully with proofs?**

Comment: You may find the article by D.R. Hayes, Brumer elements over a real quadratic base field, Expositiones Mathematicae, 1990 of interest, in particular the appendix where there is a short discussion of the 1-cocycle.

Comment: Thanks @M.Khan. I couldn't find a copy of that article in the web and in my library. Do know if there is an online copy?

Comment: I do not know. I will scan my copy and send it to you. Just send your contact info to me at khanm@easternct.edu

Comment: @M.Khan You are very kind. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The standard reference in English is the Appendix of Siegel's book "Advanced analytic number theory" (Tata Institute 1980)