# Reference for a functional equation of a Hecke L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F$ be a degree $n$ totally real number field. Let $W = (W_1,\dots ,W_n)$ be a $\mathbb Q$-basis for $F$, and let $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}W_1 + \dots + \mathbb{Z}W_n$. It is a fractional ideal in the muliplier ring $\mathcal O_\Lambda = \{\mu\in F: \mu\Lambda \subset \Lambda\}$. Let $U$ be the subgroup of totally positive units in $\mathcal O_\Lambda^\times$. Choose $\lambda\in F$ such that $\epsilon(U+\lambda) = \Lambda + \lambda$ for all $\epsilon\in U$. Finally let $\nu = \sum v_iW^*_i$ where $W^{-T}=(W^*_1,\dots,W^*_n)$.

Then in Sczech, Robert. "Eisenstein groups cocycles for GLn and values of L-functions.." Inventiones mathematicae 113.3 (1993) p.594 is defined the Hecke-L-function
$$
L(s) = \sideset{}{'}\sum_{\xi\in\Lambda+\lambda/U}\chi(\xi)\frac{\exp(2\pi i \text{tr}(\lambda - \xi)\nu)}{|N(\xi)|^s}
$$
where $\chi(\xi) = \text{sign}N(\xi)$ and the sum is taken over nonzero elements, also
$$
L^*(s) = \sideset{}{'}\sum_{\xi\in\Lambda^*+\nu/U}\chi(\xi)\frac{\exp(2\pi i \text{tr}(\nu - \xi)\lambda)}{|N(\xi)|^s},
$$
where $\Lambda^*$ is the dual lattice of $\Lambda$. The functional equation take the form
$$
i^n \det(W) G(s)L(s) = G(1-s)L^*(1-s)
$$
where $G(s)=\pi^{ns/2}\Gamma(\frac{1+s}{2})^n$, which is a 'well-known result due to Hecke' and the citation given is Siegel, C.L.: Uber die Fourierschen Koeffizienten von Modulformen. In: Gesammelte Abhandlungen IV. pp. 98-139. Berlin Heidelberg New York: Springer 1979.

The given reference has been very difficult to locate (and anyway it is in German). Is there another more accessible reference for this? I am not entirely sure how this translates into the modern setting, say in terms of Tate's thesis, so I'm not comfortable using that as an alternate reference.

Note: An [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330109/results-in-an-article-by-siegel) here gives a reference to Siegel's analytic number theory, but I haven't been able to find the above information there.

Comment: The key word here is "Poisson summation".